# Find distance using Local MeasurementSystem in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using the following method to find the distance with MeasurementSystem. Can any one confirm whether it correct way to proceed.

```
- (NSString *)textForDistance:(CLLocationDistance)meters {
    NSString *measureSystem = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleMeasurementSystem];
    BOOL isMetric = ![measureSystem isEqualToString:@"U.S."];

    NSString *distanceString;

    if (!isMetric) {
        CGFloat feet = meters / METERS_PER_FOOT;
        if (feet * 2 > FEET_PER_MILE) {
            distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f miles", (feet / FEET_PER_MILE)];
        } else {
            distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f feet",feet];
        }
    } else {
        if (meters > 1000) {
            distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f km", (meters / 1000)];
        } else {
            distanceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f meters", meters];
        }
    }

    return distanceString;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little more natural to use the `NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem` property rather than the `NSLocaleMeasurementSystem` property for this:

```
BOOL isMetric = [[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];
```

But either works. This setting is somewhat poorly defined, with lots of "well, if it isn't metric it's probably American" hints in the docs without a clear statement that in fact these are the only options and this is unlikely to change.

Comment: Rob I'm reading your book these days. (iOS 5 Programming Pushing the Limits). :-)